# C program to consume MySQL API for backup?

Tags: mysql, c, database, api, backup

I am looking for a way to backup `MySql` database use a `C` program. Does `MySql` provide API for backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, mysql does not provide any dpecific api to back a database up.

Mysql does provide the [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) utility that can be called from the command line to back up a database and also provides a [general C api](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api.html) to access a mysql server. The heneral api can be used to write your own backup program if you are unhappy with mysqldump.